# Convert little endian to decimal

Tags: sql-server-2016

Is there a way to do an on-the-fly conversion within T-SQL to convert a little Endian (something I only just learned about 20 mins ago) to a decimal value?

In the DB I'm working with, there's a table that gets updated with raw values from devices, all of which are little endian. In this immediate example, I have the value `BD 0E 00 3A`, and supposedly, this should translate to 3.773 (at least roughly). Is there a function that would allow me to immediately convert this value into my desired decimal value?

---

**EDIT 1:** I actually discovered how to translate it by finding one of the developers. It appears that the first two bytes, flipped to big endian, give the 3,773 value I need. When windows calculator is put into programmer mode, selected HEX, feeding it `0EBD` gives this result. Does someone know how I might do this same thing using T-SQL?

[image]

Comment: Can you translate "little endian" to an actual data type definition from the table? Is this binary, varbinary, what length?

Comment: In the table, it is stored as varchar.

Comment: So it's stored as a varchar(11), with four hex pairs separated by spaces? WHY? Why do people try to outsmart the database and store data in a perverse format?

Comment: In this case, the column is kind of a catch all for various values. They could be text, decimals, hex, etc. It is narrowed down and defined based on another column, EventID, that determines how to interpret the value. I didn't design it, I'm just working with it. lol

Comment: Can you ask the designers how they've determined that `BD 0E 00 3A` should translate to `3.773`?

Comment: With some further reading, it appears it's possible to convert big endian to decimal, but one must first convert little endian to big endian. With some SUBSTRING functions, I can manage that, but still, I need to know if a conversion is possible. Surely I could use a CAST or CONVERT to get past the immediate issue of it being VARCHAR, right?

Comment: Well, yes, but little endian `BD 0E 00 3A` converted to big endian is `3A 00 0E BD` and I can't figure out how either of those could possibly be converted to anything that becomes `3.773`. Can someone show how the conversion worked the other way?

Comment: Tragically, not so far. I've reached out to some senior people here, but figured I could find some info on conversion and not have to wait (the main guy is actually out this week due to medical issues). Sounds like it may be a much deeper problem if you're correct in that little or big endian, it doesn't convert to anywhere near that decimal value.

Comment: I've added some important info to the question

Comment: Ok, so the second two pieces (`00 3A`) are completely irrelevant? Did the developer explain why they are there?

Comment: He did not, but he believes they must be some other data component that is tied to the value I need (which is a voltage reading, btw). But it's at least a consistent setup I can use programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely not pretty. I can get you to an integer value of `3773`. If that is supposed to translate to 3.773 somehow, it's not clear from the data.

```
DECLARE @x varchar(32) = 'BD 0E 00 3A';

SELECT CONVERT(int, CONVERT(binary(2), 
 '0x' + RIGHT(LEFT(REPLACE(@x,' ',''),4),2) 
      + LEFT(LEFT(REPLACE(@x,' ',''),4),2),1));
```

If you know for sure there will always a space between the first two pieces, you can do this slightly simpler:

```
DECLARE @x varchar(32) = 'BD 0E 00 3A';

SELECT CONVERT(int, CONVERT(binary(2),'0x' + SUBSTRING(@x,4,2) + LEFT(@x,2), 1));
```

Tell them the next time they want to store some integers in a table, don't get cute or clever about it.